# IdentationError in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

Hello guys my code was working fine I was using Atom text editor but I switched to PyCharm IDE, next thing I know is when I hit run I keep getting this error:

```
  File "main.py", line 108
    print "***************LLENANDO NUEVOS DATOS***********************"
    ^
  IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

and here's the function so you guys can check it out and help me

```
def mostrar_orden(n_orden):
    try:
        rows_affected = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM orden WHERE norden=%s",(n_orden))
        db.commit()
        if rows_affected >= 1:
            resultados = cursor.fetchall()
            for registro in resultados:
                norden = registro[0]
                fecha = registro[1]
                marca = registro[2]
                modelo = registro[3]
                imei = registro[4]
                falla = registro[5]
                estado = registro[6]
                print "****************DATOS ACTUALES DE LA ORDEN***************************"
                print "Numero de Orden: ",norden
                print "Fecha de ingreso: ",fecha
                print "Marca: ",marca
                print "Modelo: ",modelo
                print "IMEI: ",imei
                print "Falla: ",falla
                print "Status: ",estado
                print "***************LLENANDO NUEVOS DATOS***********************"
                #fecha = raw_input("Nueva fecha: "
                fecha = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
                marca = raw_input("Nueva marca: ")
                modelo = raw_input("Nuevo modelo: ")
                imei = raw_input("Nuevo imei: ")
                falla = raw_input("Nueva falla: ")
                estado = raw_input("Nuevo status: ")
                try:
                    cursor.execute("UPDATE orden SET fecha=%s, marca=%s, modelo=%s,imei=%s,falla=%s,status=%s WHERE norden=%s",(fecha,marca,modelo,imei,falla,estado,n_orden))
                    print "Orden Actualizada!"
                except MySQLdb.Error, e:
                    print "Error: ",e[1]
                    db.rollback()
        else:
            print "Orden no encontrada verifique e intente nuevamente."
            return False
    except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
        print "Error en la consulta"
        db.rollback()
        return True
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        print "Error: ",e[1]
        db.rollback()
        return True
    return False
```

I really can't see the "error" please help me

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: yeah sounds like it, but I can't find any bad tab space =/

Comment: Are you using all spaces? PyCharm enters 4 spaces when you hit tab, if Atom doesn't do that, you probably have a mix of tabs and spaces in your code.

Comment: I think I did because I always set the editors to insert 4 tabs... anyways I'll re-write that function and see what happens =/

Answer (score 0):

You can just copypaste your code to a new file in pyCharm and the indentation error will go away.